# How can i resolve Google Sheets API - “Invalid client secret JSON file”?

Tags: php, json, google-sheets-api

I followed this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

but I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid client secret JSON file.' in /app/src/Google/Client.php:171
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 /app/quickstart.php(27):
>   Google_Client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.j...')
>
> #1 /app/quickstart.php(75): getClient()
>
> #2 {main}   thrown in /app/src/Google/Client.php on line 171

My quickstart.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'src/Google/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH','client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

// Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
$spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms';
$range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

if (count($values) == 0) {
  print "No data found.\n";
} else {
  print "Name, Major:\n";
  foreach ($values as $row) {
    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
    printf("%s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[4]);
  }
}
```

My client_secret.json:

```
{"installed":
{"client_id":"990752241706-tm7lre5go4bj4tcg7sqfc5f0u6frpsi6.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"project_id":"lead-update",
"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_secret":"[my_secret]",
"redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
"http://localhost"]}}
```

Comment: error seems clear

Comment: unfortunately not for me, because it's a valid json file

Comment: I think you have to follow this `define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');`. Did you try adding the DIR in your code?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It's the same.